# Textmate whitespace highlighting

Tags: regex, textmate

I want to modify the solution for highlighting trailing whitespace described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641794/highlighting-trailing-whitespace-in-textmate-for-python) by NOT highlighting whitespace on otherwise empty lines.

I've modified this in my Python language file:

```
        {   match = '(\s+)$';
        captures = { 1 = { name = 'invalid.whitespace'; }; };
    },
```

To this:

```
        {   match = '\S(\s+)$';
        captures = { 1 = { name = 'invalid.whitespace'; }; };
    },
```

This new expression doesn't seem to match anything anymore. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assertions:

```
(?<=\S)\s+$
```

They're described nicely in [PHP manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.php) (they're not PHP-specific of course, just php.net happens to have quite readable version of the document).

Comment: Ahh very close. It's actually (?<=\S)\s+$
Update your answer and i'll mark it as the solution. (i guess that's how this is supposed to work)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your pattern is that the preceding non-space character is presumably already matched by another rule, and thus is not available to your rule. Using an assertion as porneL suggests is the correct wayt to do this.